NPM_ERR err_ssl_cipher_operation_failed
While installing any vite or next js project, I encounter the folowing error:
npm error code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm error D00B0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:325:
npm error
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-28T13_50_06_985Z-debug-0.log

I tried every method that suggested chatGPT or Gemini. I installed node v22.12.0.
Do you have any solution for this error?

whats your npm version?

Please follow this steps: (Force clear cache and install @sap/cds-dk)

npm cache clear --force
npm i -g @sap/cds-dk
npx create-next-app@latest appName


still no luck for me :(

This is the best way for solve this issues, whatever please show me your log file message
